# mirroring traffic with iptables doesn't work

Tags: iptables, mirroring

i want to mirror specific traffic to ip 192.168.200.1
i use this solution :

[Mirror Port via iptables](https://superuser.com/questions/753294/mirror-port-via-iptables)

but when i enter following command, error occurs:

```
iptables –I PREROUTING -t mangle -j ROUTE --gw 192.168.200.1 --tee

iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--gw"
```

and when i replace "--gw" with "-gateway", like this:

```
iptables –I PREROUTING -t mangle -j ROUTE -gateway 192.168.200.1 --tee
```

this error occur:

```
iptables v1.4.12:multiple -j flag not allowed
```

why?

can help me?

tanx

Answer (score 2):

actually '--gateway' you are missing and remove that route

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -j TEE --gateway 192.162.122.62
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command does not work because gw belongs to unofficial patches, which are neither a part of netfilter, nor of the Linux kernel.

There are several such patches, described [here](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-4.html). The one you are referring to is called *ROUTE*, and is due to Cédric de Launois . You may contact him, if necessary.

At any rate, the command

```
   iptables -j THE_TARGET_YOU_WANT --help
```

(ROUTE is the target you want) will diplay the info you need, if your system already supports this patch.

EDIT:

I finally found the code for the ROUTE patch, [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/netfilter-devel@lists.samba.org/msg01285.html). You may try compiling your kernel with this patch.

Otherwise, probably the easiest solution is to use a port-mirroring ethernet switch.